# create functional object with method and object

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to create a functional object which could be called later (callback) build from
an object and a member function of that object.

```
class A
{
public:

void AnyMethod() { cout << "Hello" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    function<???>f1(&A::AnyFunc, &a); // ?????

    ...
    f1();
}
```

I am a bit confused, because creating a thread is very simple:

```
thread t1 ( &A::AnyFunc, &a); 
...
t1.join();
```

It is simple if I use it with a lamba function, but this is a bit overhead which I want to avoid.

```
function<void(void)> f2( [&a](){ a.AnyFunc(); } ); // works fine
```

Maybe there is a better way to get a callable object?

Comment: Using a lambda shouldn't add any overhead. In fact the std::function object probably adds more overhead than using an auto typed lambda.

Comment: Indeed -- lambdas are far more lightweight than `bind`, and `function<>` is going to have more overhead than either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::function<void()> f1 = std::bind(&A::AnyMethod, &a);
```